# Windows GDI BitBlt / MaskBlt across multiple displays on modern systems: Could there be DCs on different devices?

Tags: windows, winapi, gdi

While spelunking in some old code of mine I came across some codepath that deals with the case of BitBlt or MaskBlt -ing across HDCs on different displays. As per the documentation of these functions

> **BitBlt** returns an error if the source and destination device contexts represent different devices. To transfer data between DCs for
>   different devices, convert the memory bitmap to a DIB by calling
>   GetDIBits. To display the DIB to the second device, call SetDIBits or
>   StretchDIBits.

and (MaskBlt)

> When used in a multiple monitor system, both hdcSrc and hdcDest must
>   refer to the same device or the function will fail. To transfer data
>   between DCs for different devices, convert the memory bitmap
>   (compatible bitmap, or DDB) to a DIB by calling GetDIBits. To display
>   the DIB to the second device, call SetDIBits or StretchDIBits.

However this was written in a time before merged framebuffers were commonplace. These days on multi-display systems what you normally have is one large framebuffer of which (different) portions are scanned out to the display output. So logically it behaves as one single display toward GDI.

I wonder if with current versions of Windows (i.e. everything after, including Windows-7) there actually can occur a situation where HDCs acquired from windows, or created with CreateCompatibleDC may actually live on different devices?

Comment: Interestingly, the last paragraph of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/multiple-monitor-applications-on-different-systems claims `BitBlt` will cope.

Comment: This is all getting awfully dated, it's been a long long time since I've seen a video driver that allowed selecting less than 32bpp.  But blissfully without dealing with boutique hardware.  Monitor DC vs printer DC would still be a possible trouble scenario I'd imagine.

Comment: @HansPassant: Should have written in the question that I'm only bothered with display DCs. If you must know, the original code from back then deals with icon sheets to draw a lot of small status indicators (thing model railway switchboard) without doing a lot of DC state switching. I wrote this thing over 20 years ago…

Comment: Do you mean that the HDCs acquired from windows should work when you move the windows from one display to another? If yes, it should work.

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT: Well, on today's systems with their large, merged framebuffers, then yes. But 20 years ago, when you installed multiple graphics cards and it'd miraculously work in Win2k, then often you couldn't move windows between screens.